# '$ is not defined' Passing variable from javascript file to html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a variable inside my Thermostat.js file onto my webpage using index.html, the variable name I want to pass into the webpage is "roomTemp". I searched some up and this is what I've come up with but I get a reference error in my console "$ is not defined" within my javascript file at line 5 "$('#printHere').html(roomTemp);".

Thermostat.js

```
var http = require('http'); //need to http
var fs = require('fs'); //need to read static files
var roomTemp=20;
$('#printHere').html(roomTemp);

//this function is identical to the serve file function from the course web page
//it will read the contents of a file and serve them as the specified content type
//this is only used to serve the static index page
function serveStaticFile(res, path, contentType, responseCode){
   if(!responseCode) responseCode = 200;
   fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(err, data){
     if(err){
       //for now use success code
       res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
       res.end('500 INTERNAL FILE ERROR' + '\n');
     }
     else {
       res.writeHead(responseCode , {'Content-Type': contentType});
       res.end(data);
     }
   });
}

//this function is nearly identical to the routing examples from the course web page
http.createServer(function (request,response){
   var path = request.url.replace(/\/?(?:\?.*)$/,'').toLowerCase();

   switch(path){
     //serve the static index page
     case '/index.html':
       serveStaticFile(response,
                       '/index.html',
                       'text/html');
       break;

     default:
       serveStaticFile(response,
                       '/index.html',
                       'text/html');
       break;
}

}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server Running at http://127.0.0.1:3000  CNTL-C to quit');

function save() {
      var desTemp;
      desTemp = document.getElementById("desTemp").value;
      roomTemp = desTemp;
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Current Temp: <span id="printHere"></span></p>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
Desired Room Temperature: <input type="number" id="desTemp" onchange="save()"><br>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Set">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see how these files are linked at all.  You are including jQuery in your HTML, but then your thermostat.js is a node script?

Comment: Unless you include the JS file in the HTML file, nothing is going to happen.

Comment: in my html at <p>Current Temp: <span id="printHere"></span></p> I am trying to display "roomTemp" in the "printHere"

Comment: How exactly is `index.html` supposed to use the code in `Thermostat.js`?

Comment: needs more jquery.... (literally, though)

Comment: Replace `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` with `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Thermostat.js"></script>
</head>
```

You have to include these lines in you `<script src="Thermostat.js"></script>` in your head for your javascript to work. Remember defining the correct path for the src="<....\Thermostat.js">

Until you do not include your JS it won't work and also jQuery JS has to be included before your JS.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused with javascript, node.js scripts & asp.

In your thermostat.js, it's clearly a [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (server side) script. You can't mix your client-side script (jQuery) on node.js.

`$('#printHere').html(roomTemp);`

This line is trying to search through the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) and get the html values, which can't be done on the server side

### Index.html

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
```

You are creating a html page that has a form that submits to demo_form.asp, which again is another server side technology ([Active Server Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages)), by Microsoft.

Lastly, `$` is just a shorthand for [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you need to understand your software stack properly before attempting any further.